# Using h helper on operators in iex

Tags: elixir

The Elixir "Getting Started" tutorial tells me:

> For example, typing h is_integer/1 is going to print the documentation
>   for the is_integer/1 function. It also works with operators and other
>   constructs (try h ==/2).

However, if I *do* try `h ==/2`, all I get is:

```
** (SyntaxError) iex:38: syntax error before: '/'
```

Is there a newer better way of accessing help on operators?

Comment: what Elixir version you use? Also try call h(Kernel.==/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to work on latest Elixir versions (at least from v0.13.0 I believe). You can also use `h Kernel.==/2` on earlier ones.